# Accessing a component from global error handler in angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I have created an error handler in angular and i would like to access a modal component (which is registered in appmodule) and show the error in it. I am new to angular so i couldn`t figure out how to access it. Any help would be appreciated. 
Error Handler

```
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{

    handleError(error){

        alert(error);
        console.log("handeled by GlobalErrorHandler")
        console.log("error",error);
        console.log("******************");

        //instead of logging to the console, i would like to call globalModal component and show the error in a popup
    }

}
```

Global modal html

```
<div bsModal #globalModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-success" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{_modalTitle|translate}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="globalModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{_modalBody|translate}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="globalModal.hide()">Kapat</button>

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

global modal ts

```
@Component({
  selector:'GlobalModal',
  templateUrl: 'globalModal.component.html'
})



    export class GlobalModalComponent {
        @ViewChild('globalModal') globalModalElement:ModalDirective
         _modalTitle:string;
         _modalBody:string;

        show(modalTitle,modalBody){
          this._modalTitle = modalTitle;
          this._modalBody = modalBody;
          this.globalModalElement.show();
        }

     }
```

Comment: i think you should use a shared service pass the error to a service and then access the service variable and display the error . more on [shared services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)